# Cordova visual studio ios agent configuration

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2012, certificate, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to test my Cordova application in iOS, I followed all the steps that included in https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn757054.aspx#ios

When configuring Visual Studio `-->tools-->options--->tools for Apache Cordova`, I get this error :

> An error occurred trying to acquire certificate from [Host].

I have an Apple developer ID, and I am already logged in in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by placing the IP address of the host in the Host field, rather than the host name.

Comment: Thank you bro, I solved this issue by launching the remotebuild without security. 
remotebuild --secure=false;

Answer (score 0):

Be sure after doing all of this to also type remotebuild on the command line of the mac to prepare it to receive the build from your pc :-) ... Think of it like bluetooth pairing..

Answer (score 0):

- Replace host name using IP address MacBook and try again.
- If this does not work then following are steps to reset remotebuild:
- first stop server using following command:
   `cntrl + c`

  1. Execute following command to reset remotebuild certificates:

     `remotebuild certificates reset`
  2. Run following to command to regenerate remotebuild server:

     `remotebuild certificates generate`
- here, new secure pin number will be generated.

  3. Following command to start remotebuild:

     `remotebuild`
- now try again, make sure 'Enable remote iOS processing' is true and 'Secure mode' is true and valid secure number is added.